# How do I enable pgadmin4 (PostgreSQL12) to read and write files in directories of other Linux Users on RHEL8/CentOS8

Tags: permissions, centos, postgresql-12, pgadmin-4, redhat

While trying to export a query result set from PGAdmin4 on PostgreSQL12 to a CSV I am encountering the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not open file "/home/linuxusername/Downloads/data.csv" for reading: Permission denied
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
SQL state: 42501
```

I'm somewhat new to PGAdmin but am familiar with Linux and SQL. Is there a configuration setting that I'm unaware of to allow PGAdmin to read and write to files and directories of Linux users?

Using the `/tmp` works fine, but it's a pain to have to keep moving files to and from other directories and it's seriously cramping my work flow and slowing me down. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the folder can not be acessed by the service, so choose another folder or see the rights to the folder

Comment: I assume I could add a group to a user that would allow file read/write permissions from PGAdmin. Which user or group does pgadmin4 use by default? I've tried adding a user to the `postgres` group but that didn't seem to work. Perhaps I'm missing something more?